# Trapping Object required: '[object]' with MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0

Tags: xml, asp-classic

I am using the Flickr API and MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0 to read the XML response.

For example:

https://www.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search&api_key=[mykey]&text=cheese&per_page=1&sort=relevance&min_upload_date=2010-05-25

Returns:

```
<rsp stat="ok">
    <photos page="1" pages="847622" perpage="1" total="847622">
        <photo id="8658999887" owner="46248160@N04" secret="13e2615193" server="8123" farm="9" title="cheeses" ispublic="1" isfriend="0" isfamily="0"/>
    </photos>
</rsp>
```

I do some simple ASP to set variable values:

```
vurl = https://www.flickr.com/services/rest/?method=flickr.photos.search&api_key=[mykey]&text=cheese&per_page=1&sort=relevance&min_upload_date=2010-05-25
Set http = Server.CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")
http.Open "GET", vurl, False
http.Send

Set dom = http.responseXML

Set items = dom.getElementsByTagName("photos")

If NOT (items IS Nothing) Then

    For Each item In items

        Set tags = item.getElementsByTagName("photo")
        If NOT (tags IS Nothing) Then 
            var_id = tags(0).getAttribute("id")
            var_owner = tags(0).getAttribute("owner")
            var_server = tags(0).getAttribute("server")
            var_farm = tags(0).getAttribute("farm")
            var_title = tags(0).getAttribute("title")
            var_public = tags(0).getAttribute("public")
            var_secret = tags(0).getAttribute("secret")
            var_img_url2 = "https://farm"&var_farm&".staticflickr.com/"&var_server&"/"&var_id&"_"&var_secret&"_b.jpg"
            var_id = ""
            %>
            <%
        End If

    Next

end if
```

My problem is that if there is no image returned by the API for a search term - e.g. "aplogranite" the XML response is:

```
<rsp stat="ok">
    <photos page="1" pages="0" perpage="1" total="0"/>
</rsp>
```

My code above returns this error:

```
Microsoft VBScript runtime error '800a01a8'

Object required: '[object]'
```

I tried trapping it via:

```
Set items = dom.getElementsByTagName("photos")

If NOT (items IS Nothing) Then...
```

But it still errors.

I wondered how I could trap the error so that I can handle the scenario where the XML does not contain any data within the "photo" tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems that instead of `Nothing`, `getElementsByTagName()` returns empty collection in the case when no element match tag name parameter. So try to check `Length` of the return value instead :

```
If tags.Length > 0 Then
    ....
End If
```

Or maybe test the first element for `Nothing` :

```
If Not (tags(0) Is Nothing) Then
    ....
End If
```

Comment: The [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms762212%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) supports this: "The IXMLDOMNodeList object is returned even if there are no matches. In this case, the length of the list will be set to zero."