# Classic ASP - Show XML Record

Tags: xml, asp-classic

I'm trying to get the username and dbId of each record.

Here is the code so you can see how I tried, but I'm stuck.

***I only know how to get the first record (0) but how to I loop through all of them ?***

Thanks so much in advance for any help.

**CODE:**

```
    Set http = Server.CreateObject("msxml2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")
    http.Open "GET", "http://URLWHERETHEXMLFILEISAT.COM", False, "USERNAME", "PASSWORD"
    http.setTimeouts 5000, 5000, 10000, 10000 'ms - resolve, connect, send, receive'
    http.setRequestHeader "Authorization", "Basic MY_AUTH_STRING"
    http.Send

Response.ContentType = "application/xml"    

Set items = http.responseXML.getElementsByTagName("list")

For Each item In items
'--> I would like to display the username and dbId for each record

Set username = item.getElementsByTagName("username")
    If NOT (username IS Nothing) Then 
        var_username = username(0).Text
    End If


response.write "Username: " & var_username & "</br>"

Response.write "</br>"
Next
```

**.XML FILE**

```
<list>
<com.pedigree.external.User>
<dbId>1353</dbId>
<url>/api/users/1353</url>
<parentId>126561</parentId>
<firstName>JOHN</firstName>
<lastName>WILLIAMS</lastName>
<email/>
<username>johnw</username>
<cellPhone/>
<workPhone/>
<actorClass>User Driver</actorClass>
<active>true</active>
<isDriver>true</isDriver>
<customerId>2235470</customerId>
</com.pedigree.external.User>
<list>
```

Comment: Use XPath, in a call to SelectNodes() , then iterate through the resulting nodeset.  See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms754523(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: `getElementsByTagName` returns a collection, as documentation attests: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms765549(v=vs.85).aspx
So you can use `Length` property to loop through using a `For`
Here is another question about this:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30045001/trapping-object-required-object-with-msxml2-serverxmlhttp-6-0